# Single utility project but multiple use

Tags: c#, .net, csproj

I can't think of a more precise title on this question - please update if you do have one.
I'm looking for an elegant solution to the following problem:
Given

- Project A Pa
- Project B Pb
- Project C Pc

Given

- Library 1 L1
- Library 2 L2
- Library 3 L3

I'd like some extensions (i.e. classes, extension methods) on L1. Pa and Pb wants to use L1 extensions. Solution: Create ExtensionsLibrary Lx1 and reference Lx1 in Pa and Pb.

Then, I'd like some extensions on L2. Pb and Pc wants to use L2 extensions, so I create ExtensionsLibrary Lx2 and refernce it in Pb and Pc.

More ideal would be to have solution Lx (a single ExtensionsLibrary) with a dependency on L1 *and* L2. But now, when I reference Lx in Pb the transitive dependencies also got added! That's not what I want - if Pa does not use L2, it should not be an unused transitive dependency.

Is there a way to still have only one ExtensionsLibrary Lx without having Pa introduce transitive dependency L2 and Pc introduce transitive dependency L1?

Comment: If you add a dependency, you also pull in all the dependencies of that dependency. That's how it works. "when I reference Lx in Pb the transitive dependencies also got added" - exactly

Comment: Right! That's why I'm asking if any alternative solutions exist to this problem.